# "Do you wanna talk about it?" vs. "Do you wanna talk about that?"

Tags: differences

Recently, I've been thinking a lot about the everyday usage of "it" and "that". For instance, "Mate, it sucks." 
              "Mate, that sucks." 
              "Yes, I saw it." 
              "Yes, I saw that." 
In terms of meaning, is there any difference? Is there any given rule that has to be applied? Thank you for your replies!

Comment: Do we gotta recognize "wanna"?

Comment: Maybe a (subtle) difference of referencing: *it* = the thing *referenced* (the actual thing itself); *that* = the thing '*pointed*' to (which resolves to *it* after one level of indirection).

Answer (score 5):

I'd say that "it" can act like a **generalisation** of "that".

For example:

> "I got fired again"
>
> "Mate, it sucks" - could be a reference to the job market in general,
>   and a form of agreement, with the speaker implying it has happened to
>   them too.
>
> "I got fired again"
>
> "Mate, that sucks" - more clearly a reference to the specific
>   incident, and an expression of empathy for the other's misfortune.

In other words, while "that" is the thing being discussed, "it" could be something else, most likely a wider situation of which "that" is an example.

This isn't a rule, it's more like a possible usage.  Sometimes "it" and "that" can refer to the same thing, which seems more likely to be the case with your second example, "I saw it" vs "I saw that".